# Transact SQL: SUM with a LIKE Statment

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to sum a column while using the LIKE statement to group another?

Ex. I need to add together total labor hours by department (similar Labor Codes):

```
Code    Hours
L0101   5.25
L0104   39
L0201   60.5
L0202   95.5
L0203   65
L0204   44.5
L0301   24
L0302   70
L0303   121.5
L0305   119

results:
L0100s  44.25
L0200s  265.5
L0300s  334.5
```

Comment: `GROUP BY SUBSTRING...`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using like but gives the results your are showing.

```
Select
  Substring(code,1,2) as Code3, Sum(Hours) as TotalHours
from table
group by
  Substring(code,1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to repeat the function in group by to get what you want:

```
select left(Code,3) + '00s' as Department,
       sum(Hours) as Hours
from Table
group by left(Code,3) + '00s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by the first 3 letter of the labor code:

```
SELECT      LaborCode  = LEFT(Code, 3) + '00s',
            TotalHours = SUM([Hours])
FROM        my_table
GROUP BY    LEFT(Code, 3)
```

Comment: This is perfect! tyvm